# How can I make VS Code format C/C++ function return types on their own line?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-code, code-formatting

I'm on macOS. GNU C++ in Visual Studio Code automatically format like

```
int
main ()
{
 ...
}
```

Instead I want to do :

```
int main()
{
 ...
}
```

Follows my current settings:

```
  "[cpp]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-vscode.cpptools"
  },
  "C_Cpp.clang_format_fallbackStyle": "{ BasedOnStyle: GNU, IndentWidth: 2, IncludeBlocks: Merge, IndentGotoLabels: true, KeepEmptyLinesAtTheStartOfBlocks: true}",
```

Comment: You may find this site helpful: https://clang-format-configurator.site/